# C# Gridview datasource to datatable

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, telerik, datasource

I'm trying to convert a gridview datasource to a datatable.

What I have tried so far

```
dt = (DataTable)GridCanvas.DataSource; // Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 to type 'System.Data.DataTable'
```

Also I have tried this

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CRM.Models.Leads]' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource'
BindingSource bindingSource = (BindingSource)GridCanvas.DataSource;
                dt = (DataTable)bindingSource.DataSource;
```

And this

```
 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
  dt = GridCanvas.DataSource as DataTable;
```

I'm populating my gridview in the following way

```
 var dispatchLeads = await API.Zelkon.Leads.Dispatch.Leads(Variables.Agent.username);
        GridCanvas.DataSource = dispatchLeads;
```

I'm trying to avoid loop solutions. Hope someone has an idea how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: `await API.Zelkon.Leads.Dispatch.Leads` return's a generic list (`CRM.Models.Leads`) you can't cast a list to a data table like that; tables have columns and rows. You'll need to create a datatable with the columns you need and then add all the objects from your list into the datatable.

Comment: Cast to List<Leads> rather than DataTable.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Codexer maybe I wasn't explaining myself properly, the data is already in the gridview's datasource. Now I want to extract it to a datatatable

Comment: I know you want a `DataTable`, please read my comment again.

Comment: Can you let us know how you have bind data to GridCanvas? Is the datasource is a List<CRM.Models.Leads> or something else?

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly is returned from… `var dispatchLeads = await API.Zelkon.Leads.Dispatch.Leads(Variables.Agent.username);` … We can guess from the errors that it is not a `DataTable` nor a `BindingSource` so what is it? I will assume it is a `List<Leads>` and as Codexer noted… there is no built-in mechanism to convert a `List<T>` to a `DataTable` … your code will have to do this. Also noted is if you already have a `List<Lead>`… why do you need a `DataTable`? What do you need to do that the `List<Lead>` does not provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
 First get the List<Leads> from GridCanvas as 
 List<Leads> data=(List<Leads>)GridCanvas.DataSource;
 Then Convert the List<Leads> to DataTable as;
 DataTable dt=ToDataTable<Leads>(data);
 use following methods for conversion.
 public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```